# Kotlin map: get associated values

Tags: kotlin

I'm still trying to understand map. The intent is for the user to enter a score and use that as a key to the assotiated value (points).

```
private val scoreModel = ScoreModel()

private lateinit var textEditMdl: EditText
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_acft)

    textEditMdl = findViewById(R.id.newAcft_textEdit_mdl)

    newAcft_btn_save.setOnClickListener {
        calculateMdl(textEditMdl)
    }
}
private fun calculateMdl(rawScore: EditText): Double? {
    val rawScore = rawScore.text.toString()
    val key: Double? = rawScore.toDoubleOrNull()
    val value = scoreModel.eventMDL.values
    val valueMdl = value.toDoubleArray()

    if (value.contains(key)) {
            return valueMdl[0]
        }else {
        return 0.0
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What happens when this code is run? What is that wrong/insufficient?

Comment: (Good call, @underscore_d.  As I always say: every bug report or question needs three things: what you did, what you saw as a result, and why that's wrong — or, equivalently, what you expected to see instead.  All three parts need to be present, in enough detail to understand and recreate the problem.  Far too often that last part is missing.)

Comment: Good feedback, I will ensure these questions are in future posts. 1. I set up a TextView to display the Value next to the TextEdit (Score). When the button gets tapped I expected to see the value appear at the 0 index. I could not get this to work so i assumed my code was wrong.  I am coming from Swift so i would pass in the $index and map over the values. I am not sure how I can do this in Kotlin.